# Selenium WebDriver, Chrome. I am getting errors NOT IMPLEMENTED during (in the beginning and ending) running Python tests

Tags: google-chrome, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Errors:

```
[6944:3028:0128/220426:ERROR:chrome_views_delegate.cc(176)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[6944:3028:0128/220426:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENT
ED
[6944:3028:0128/220430:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENT
```

Read that the problem is in versions of Google Chrome and chromedriver.exe but I have the last version of Google Chrome - 32.0.1700.102 m and chromedriver.exe - 2.8.
Test runs fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just the console output from ChromeDriver, which does't indicate anything wrong with the tests. You can silence these outputs in order to avoid them on the console.  Refer this link: [Silencing Chrome driver console outputs when I run my tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847140/silencing-chrome-driver-console-outputs-when-i-run-my-tests).

Comment: The link does not actually have a solution.