# ERROR chrome_views_delegate.cc(185) -- NOT IMPLEMENTED

Tags: dart, code-reuse, dart-polymer, dart-pub

### Opportunity:

Hello, I have a situation that I simply can't figure-out. I am getting these errors from Dart when I run a quite simple example:

```
 [13288:9212:0320/161303:ERROR:navigation_entry_screenshot_manager.cc(147)] Invalid entry with unique id: 3

 [14080:11508:0320/155717:ERROR:chrome_views_delegate.cc(185)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
 [14080:11508:0320/155717:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(753)] NOT IMPLEMENTED

 [14080:11508:0320/155719:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(753)] NOT IMPLEMENTED

 [14080:11508:0320/155747:ERROR:extension_icon_image.cc(201)] Start loading extension icon for Chromium. scale = 1
```

The messages don't really connect to the Use-Case I'm implementing.  My attempts to use debug and other tools have come to *not much indeed*.   I have 'reduced' the problem to a simple example based on the DartPolymer example:

- [**Define a Custom Element**](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/polymer-intro/) tutorial.

This tutorial defines a DartPolymer component called `<tut-stopwatch>`.  In my example I have copied that element as two clones: `<x-fred>` and `<z-fred>`.  Everything is identical in a ***diff*** command, except the names and tags.

The layout of the main **index**.html page is as follows:

```dart
<body>
    <x-fred> </x-fred>
    <hr/>    
    <h1>Stopwatch</h1>
    <tut-stopwatch> </tut-stopwatch>
    <hr/>    
    <z-fred> </z-fred>
</body>
```

### Investigation so far:

I put a break-point on the DOM register call and the stopwatch creator (*constructor*):

```dart
 class TuteStopwatch extends PolymerElement {
   @observable String counter='00:00';

   TuteStopwatch.created() : super.created();

     :     
}
```

The "*unique id message*" as I call it comes up:

```dart
[13288:9212:0320/161303:ERROR:navigation_entry_screenshot_manager.cc(147)] Invalid entry with unique id: 3
```

During debugging.  There's no clear connection to the code executing and I think that this is an async message, unrelated to the registration of the  `<tut-stopwatch>` component.

The other two examples (*different in name and a label only*): `<x-fred>` and `<z-fred>` work fine.  It is just the  `<tut-stopwatch>` element that poses a problem.

This is *difficult* for two reasons:

1. I have a stand-alone  `<tut-stopwatch>` example working fine.
2. Despite text and lexical code-compare of three bits of "***congruent***" code, one is flawed in a specific context.  It speaks to a lack of robustness some place.

Obviously I need a bit of direction on where to look for the problem.  It reminds me of those games: "*One of these things is not like the other . . .* "

Thanks in advance.

---

## Code

### <**tut-stopwatch**>

Based on: [**Define a Custom Element**](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/polymer-intro/) example:

```dart
 // Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
 // for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
 // BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

 import 'dart:html';
 import 'dart:async';
 import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

 @CustomTag('tute-stopwatch')
 class TuteStopwatch extends PolymerElement {
   @observable String counter='00:00';

   TuteStopwatch.created() : super.created();

   Stopwatch mywatch = new Stopwatch();
   Timer mytimer;
   :


 }
```

### <**x-fred**>

```dart
@CustomTag('x-fred')
//@CustomTag('tute-stopwatch')
class XFred extends PolymerElement {
  @observable String counter='00:00';

  XFred.created() : super.created();

  Stopwatch mywatch = new Stopwatch();
  Timer mytimer;


   Stopwatch mywatch = new Stopwatch();
   Timer mytimer;
   :


 }
```

- **Note**: each element is in a different sub-folder and there is no name space collision between on the `TuteStopwatch{...}` class with `<x-fred>` and `<z-fred>`

---

### tut_stopwatch.html

This file is in its own folder with tute_stopwatch.dart:

- elements/fred/tute_stopwatch.html

  ```dart
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
          background-color: yellow;
          text-align: center;
          display: inline-block;
          border: solid 1px;
          padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <div>
      <div> stopwatch: 
        {{counter}}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button on-click="{{start}}" id="startButton">Start</button>
        <button on-click="{{stop}}"  id="stopButton">Stop</button>
        <button on-click="{{reset}}" id="resetButton">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script type="application/dart" src="tute_stopwatch.dart"> </script>
  ```

### fred.html (<**x-fred**>)

This file is in its own folder with Fred.dart:

- elements/fred/fred.html

  ```dart
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
          background-color: blue;
          text-align: center;
          display: inline-block;
          border: solid 1px;
          padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <div>
      <div> fred: 
        {{counter}}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button on-click="{{start}}" id="startButton">Start</button>
        <button on-click="{{stop}}"  id="stopButton">Stop</button>
        <button on-click="{{reset}}" id="resetButton">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script type="application/dart" src="fred.dart">  </script>
  ```

Comment: Have you tried if the error goes away when you change the class name of x-fred? Might be a bug.

Comment: Thanks [Günter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/gunter-zochbauer), I changed each class' name to: XStopwatch and ZStopwatch -- Same problem with the original TuteStopwatch class (or tut_Stopwatch.html)

Comment: Can you post the HTML code of `<tute-stopwatch>` and `<x-fred>`? Have you checked that the HTML of each tag points to the correct `*.dart` file?

Comment: Added the HTML and modified the fred class: XFred.  I'm pretty convinced it is a bug since the stopwatch itself works fine in another project.

Comment: One thing.  I have also purged the shadow Packages symlinks and the Packages cache to ensure everything is built to the latest release.

Comment: What versions are you using (Dart, Polymer). Have you tried `pub upgrade`? If yes this might be a bug but I wonder because it's such a simple application and Polymer works quite good for me recently also in more complex scenarios.

Comment: I did a complete delete for the Pacakges Cache.  The current version are ... Dart = [Dart VM version: 1.2.0 (Tue Feb 25 06:18:15 2014) on "windows_ia32"], Polymer-Dart = 0.9.5 (there's a v10 but is is buggy).  This is Windows 7/64-bit.  Not sure if that 32-bit option is a killer.

Comment: What problem did you have with 0.10.0? This might also only be a problem with Dart 1.2 but not with 1.3.0-dev.x.

Comment: The problem persisted with the beta; [Dart VM version: 1.3.0-dev.4.1 (Sun Mar 16 12:31:12 2014) on "windows_ia32"]

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Can you make the project available as a github project. When I find time I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

### github

I have put the failing case on GitHub here:
 - https://github.com/aplatypus/dart-experiments

This version fails to show the tute-stopwatch element.  Yet clones with a different name work OK.  Same code, just different names.

### work-around

I can report that I have a work-around.  I'm more or less convinced that its a Dart or Dart Editor bug though.

The fix was to manually rename: <**tute-stopwatch**> to: <**x-stopwatch**>

The x-stopwatch version of the (same) code then worked a-OK.   Then I renamed the custom element back again to:

- <**tute-stopwatch**>

And now the: <**tute-stopwatch**> is working.

I don't think its a satisfying resolution because I pretty much purged the project folder and Packages cache a couple of times.  There be something hanging about me thinks.

Also I'm still seeing odd errors:

```
F:\.bin\dev\dart\dev\chromium\Chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=59082 --user-data-dir=C:\Users\william\.dartium --enable-experimental-web-platform-features --enable-html-imports --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --no-process-singleton-dialog chrome://version/
[18040:16896:0322/210119:ERROR:chrome_views_delegate.cc(185)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[18040:16896:0322/210119:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(753)] NOT IMPLEMENTED

[18040:16896:0322/210121:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(753)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
```

When I completely remove the tute-stopwatch element the messages go away, but I still see this:

```
[18040:16896:0322/210647:ERROR:navigation_entry_screenshot_manager.cc(147)] Invalid entry with unique id: 6
```

The number for '*unique id*' changes from run to run of course.

I figured I'd post the outcome.  If you have a similar situation try a different name for the element in question.  That may help someone facing similar *weirdness*.

Comment: I found a question with a similar error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423486
For me this indicates that you are doing something in an unusual way. Can you publish your entire project on github so I can try to reproduce?

Comment: I don't get the errors you mentioned but `z-fred` is not show here too. I'll investigate further later and keep you updated.

Comment: You have mixed `tut-stopwatch` and `tute-stopwatch` (`index.html`, `tute_stopwatch.html` `name='tut-stopwatch' and `tute_stopwatch.dart` `@CustomTag('tute-stopwatch')`) must all use the same tag name. Correct it and it works fine.